# Push Configuration Profile OTA

Tags: ios, mdm, android, configuration-profile

I have setted up a MDM server which could push apps to the user over the air. But the serious issue I am facing is that the number of people enrolled is only about 50%. I like to push the configuration profile into the mobile, once the user connect their device to the corporate wifi. Right now I kept the profile in the webserver and ask the users to enroll their devices with the weblink.

I would also like to setup the MDM environment for Android. Where should I start? Wherever I serch, I was redirected to [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html). The sample code link available in this page redirects to a page where sample of android app code is given. Unlike iPhone is it is necessary to have a app to do MDM in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Android requires an app to be installed on Android device. THis app is allowed to do some of functionality which iOS MDM protocol provides you.

However, it's way more limited than iOS. Generally speaking, iOS MDM was gradually improved over 3 major iOS releases and it's pretty robust.

Android DeviceAdmin functionality almost didn't change after initial release. Different vendors (Samsung, Motorolla) released their own extensions to bridge the gap.

Also, Android doesn't define client-server protocol. So, you will have to define your own protocol to deliver equivalent of commands/configuration profiles to Android devices.

You can look at open source MDM which support MDM:
http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/